# C++ template functions are automatically static? (No, they aren't)

Tags: c++, templates, static

When you write a template function (or member) you have to write the body in the header file. This makes perfect sense since templates are essentially instructions to the compiler how to make functions on the fly based on a type unknown until the initialization.

My question is connected to the one definition rule, if I initialize a template with the same type (for example **typename T** becomes **int**) in two different files and I link them together I do not have a multiple definition error.

What is the reason? Are template functions implicitly **static** and so not visible outside their compilation unit?

Or there is another reason?

Answer:
No. They aren't. They are an exception to the one definition rule.

Comment: A better model would be to consider them to be implicitly `inline`.

Comment: A function template is not a function, so there's a separate part of the one-definition-rule that applies to function templates. Those rules imply that all instantiations of the same function template specialization are the same, and they must indeed be deduplicated by the translator. (E.g. all functions `f<int>` share the same block-local static variables.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard contains a special exception in the one definition rule for templates.

N4140, emphasis mine:

> **3.2 One definition rule [basic.def.odr]**
>
> 6 There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), inline function with external linkage (7.1.2), class template (Clause 14), **non-static function template (14.5.6)**, static data member of a class template (14.5.1.3), member function of a class template (14.5.1.1), or template specialization for which some template parameters are not specified (14.7, 14.5.5) in a program provided that each definition
> appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. [...]

Those following requirements effectively state that all definitions are required to be identical, but I'm assuming they are in your code.

You can tell that template functions are neither implicitly `inline` nor implicitly `static` by the fact that this program works:

a.cc:

```
template <typename T> T f();
int main() { return f<int>(); }
```

b.cc:

```
template <typename T> T f() { return T(); }
template int f();
```

If templates were implicitly `inline`, this program would be invalid because an `inline` function must be defined in every translation unit where it is used.

If templates were implicitly `static`, this program would be invalid because the definition in `b.cc` would not be found to match the declaration in `a.cc`.

Comment: Very interesting example, time ago I tried the same with an inline function: **inline int f() { return 1; }** in one file and **int f(); int main() { return f(); }** in another to see if inline function are implicitly static (they are). Instead templates work differently.

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni Those are not implicitly `static` either. They do require a definition in each translation unit where they are used. However, those definitions get merged: if you obtain the address of `f` in one translation unit, and compare that to the address of `f` obtained from another translation unit, you'll find they're the same.

Comment: Shouldn't that last line of code be `template<> int f<int>();` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt No, it's supposed to be an explicit instantiation, not a specialisation.

Comment: Ok, then `template int f<int>();`

Comment: @BenVoigt That would be valid too, but it's not necessary to specify the template argument if it can be deduced.

Comment: I was unaware that return types participated in deduction.  Apparently they do in limited cases.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, another example where they do is in conversions to function pointer types: `int (*fp)() = f;` works too.

Comment: @hvd are you sure? I tried to a make an inline function with a static variable inside and the behavior is like each function as its own copy of static the variable. I guess it might be a bug of the compiler, though...

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni Quite sure. Given `inline int f() { static int i; return ++i; }`, if I call this function twice from different TUs and print the results, I see `1` followed by `2` as expected, with GCC 4.9.2. This matches the standard: "A `static` local variable in an `extern inline` function always refers to the same object." (The keyword `extern` is optional, functions are `extern` by default, it's only mentioned here because it doesn't apply to `static inline` functions.) Can you show a concrete program and compiler that produces different results?