# How the linking phase handles template definitions

Tags: c++

Template classes/functions are generated at compile time so, what happens when:

- temp.h contains a template function or class
- A.cpp uses temp.h's function using int as the type
- B.cpp uses temp.h's function using int as the type

A and B get compiled, presumably now both object outputs have a function using type int inside of them now. Normally if you define the same thing twice and try to link, errors. So how is the generated definition any different, since it's conceptually suppose to be just a generated definition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ template functions are automatically static? (No, they aren't)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916602/c-template-functions-are-automatically-static-no-they-arent)

Comment: The late lamented Watcom C++ compiler did this by generating template function definitions into the .COM ('common') section of the object file. Common stuff in the common section isn't repeated by the linker and doesn't trigger duplication errors.